# Printing value into particular form textbox value when clicking anchar tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have below dynamic div tag structure into a form. i want to print a value into particular text field value among all.when particular link clicked. i have written my codes below.

```
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-0">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-0" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-1">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-1" class="input-class"value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-2">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-2" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i exactly want is,
if clicked link with id of **my_id-0**, a value for a text box near to clicked link should be added in a dynamic way. how do i do that?

Comment: I think this is a basic use of jquery, you should first learn by yourself.

Comment: @fish_ball it's also trivial using regular JS. Still, jQuery is going to be shorter and easier to type. Whatever the case, the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `id`s should be unique in html code, so remove it and use class as shown below:

```
<div class="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-0">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-0" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-1">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-1" class="input-class"value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-2">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-2" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use following jQuery to print values :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a[id^=my_id]').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).next().find('.input-class').val('your print value');
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_id-0').siblings('div').children('input').value(yourValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest, and ID's should be unique

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('input[type="text"]').val($(this).attr("href"));
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

the below codes works to me.

my jaquery,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('a').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).next().find('.input-class').val('your print value');
      });
   });
```

my html,

```
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-0">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-0" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-1">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-1" class="input-class"value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <a href="some url" id="my_id-2">click</a>
  <div>
    <input type="textbox" id="my-input-2" class="input-class" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all for the reply.